# ORA-00904 invalid identifier code

Tags: oracle10g

Please help me with this code. i try to create a table but it keep poping out the error ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

```
CREATE TABLE tblParentMaster
    ( HOHCodeid VARCHAR2(10),
    Parent1 VARCHAR2(10),
    Address VARCHAR2(30),
    Home_Phone_Number CHAR(10),
    Address1 VARCHAR2(30),
    City VARCHAR2(20),
    States CHAR(2),
    Zip CHAR(5),
    Parent2Code VARCHAR2(10),
    Parent2 VARCHAR2(10),
    Address2 VARCHAR2(30),
    Volunteer CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'N',
    Email VARCHAR2(20),
        CONSTRAINT pk_tblParentMaster_HOHCode PRIMARY KEY (HOHCode),
        CONSTRAINT nn_tblParentMaster_Parent1 NOT NULL (Parent1),
        CONSTRAINT ck_tblParentMaster_Volunteer CHECK (Volunteer IN ('Y', 'N'))
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't how you declare a not-null constraint. You can either have a named constraint, as [shown in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52235):

```
...
Parent1 VARCHAR2(10),
...
CONSTRAINT nn_tblParentMaster_Parent1 CHECK (Parent1 is NOT NULL)
...
```

Or declare it in-line, which won't have a nice name:

```
...
Parent1 VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
...
```

Your PK is wrong as well, you don't have a column called just HOHCode:

```
CONSTRAINT pk_tblParentMaster_HOHCode PRIMARY KEY (HOHCodeId),
```

So:

```
CREATE TABLE tblParentMaster
    ( HOHCodeid VARCHAR2(10),
    Parent1 VARCHAR2(10),
    Address VARCHAR2(30),
    Home_Phone_Number CHAR(10),
    Address1 VARCHAR2(30),
    City VARCHAR2(20),
    States CHAR(2),
    Zip CHAR(5),
    Parent2Code VARCHAR2(10),
    Parent2 VARCHAR2(10),
    Address2 VARCHAR2(30),
    Volunteer CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'N',
    Email VARCHAR2(20),
        CONSTRAINT pk_tblParentMaster_HOHCode PRIMARY KEY (HOHCodeId),
        CONSTRAINT nn_tblParentMaster_Parent1 CHECK (Parent1 is NOT NULL),
        CONSTRAINT ck_tblParentMaster_Volunteer CHECK (Volunteer IN ('Y', 'N'))
);

table TBLPARENTMASTER created.
```